# /v1/billing/subscriptions/I-XXXXXXXX/revise RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND cannot revise plan

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am following this documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions/

I can make a get subscription request and I do find the resource, so it does exists, I'm trying to change a plan for user with no success.

I have tried multiple subscriptions upgrades and keep getting this error:

```
{
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "badd307417e54",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm testing my personal user on production environment.

Request made using postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-XXXXXX/revise' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX' \
--data-raw '{"plan_id":"P-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}'
```

Comment: Then show us the code you are using to do this

Comment: I've added a postman screenshot, it a simple post request, getting the same error on the production environment

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Thank you, will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting here I have found other questions about the `/revise` endpoint, none was answered, after that we have initiated a communication with PayPal's merchant support and apparently there is a bug.

The issue was escalated to PayPal's engineers, not sure when it will be resolved.

If anyone else is having this issue at the moment and is looking to change a plan, we have found a functioning workaround:

- Create a new subscription - Users need approve the new price on PayPal
- You will have to manually calculate the first payment in case of an upgrade
- Once the new subscription activated - cancel the old subscription

We didn't find a way update an existing subscription plan

I hope it will help someone save some time

Answer (score 0):

It appears the plan you are attempting to revise the subscription to (inexplicably obfuscated in your question as "P-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") is not valid.

Provide a valid Plan ID.

Comment: All ID's and tokens that I use are valid, I have masked the original ID's as this are not relevant to my question. each account will have it's own tokens and ID's anyway so publishing production ID's did not make sense to me

Comment: No, they are not valid.  And your question is impoverished for not including full details on the thing causing the problem (invalid plan_id)

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, I'm choosing not to disclose private information, at least you didn't ask me to share the API token, it is also not valid.

Comment: You got an API response that is not an authentication error. Your API token is valid. The plan_id is not valid, however. And the question contains zero information about the plan_id's creation and status